# bit data type in JSON

Tags: json, sql-server, xml

I have a table that stored 'bit' type values. In my SQL procedure I call that field to make my output of XML format and I convert that output to JSON online. Doing so, my JSON output does not obey 'bit' fields.

My current JSON output:

```
{
   "fakedata": "something..",
   "question1": "test answer",
   "question2": "a"
   "question3": "1"
   "question4": "0"
   }
}
```

In this format, I want question 3&4 to be bit like

desired JSON structure:

```
{
   "fakedata": "something..",
   "question1": "test answer",
   "question2": "a"
   "question3": 1
   "question4": 0
   }
}
```

Any guidance?

Answer (score -1):

- Try converting the BIT to INT (author said this did not work).
- Check the XML result (post it here). Does it look right in XML? Then...
- Run the XML result through your online conversion process manually to see if that's the culprit.

Comment: I am confident in posting this question since I tried converting bit to int, checked my XML output with online transformer as well!